# UriFormatException - how to see the malformed data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to access this value...

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

and getting the UriFormatException.   Is there a way to get a string representation of the malformed data?

Comment: All of the headers are available through the request's `Headers` collection.

Comment: How would I access that?   HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[0]?  A foreach loop?

Comment: It seems like you need a key or value datum to obtain anything?  How would one list a complete set of headers?

Comment: Perhaps using the name of the header?

Comment: I don't know what that is.  I want to find out what the referring data is.  I don't know where it is coming from.

Comment: Is there a way to just print out the complete list of headers.  So I can see what's malformed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to access that.  A code snippet would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Request.Headers.AllKeys` should give you a list of all the header keys.

Headers is a [NameValueCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=netframework-4.8) , so you should be able to get the referer value by simply doing:

```
Request.Headers.GetValues("Referer").FirstOrDefault()
```

There's an [example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.headers?view=netframework-4.8#examples) for printing out all the headers.